# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_" referenced from error xcode when trying to access subproject files

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using a subproject within my xcode project with files I want to access in my main project. I have put the directories to these files in my "Header Search Paths" in my build settings, so when I import them I don't get any compiler errors. I have the subproject files added to the the compile sources in the Build Phases of my subproject. I have my main project's files added to the compile sources of my main project. However, when I try to build, I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_LoginService", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GettingStartedViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ProfileService", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GettingStartedViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas on fixing this? Is there a good way to add the subproject's files to the compile sources of the main project? When I do this, it creates a separate group in xcode without actually adding the files to the compile sources of the main project.
Thanks!

Comment: What do your subproject targets create?

Comment: For future users: https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial follow this tutorial. search for adding "dependency" on this page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linker is complaining because it cannot find those symbols. Assuming that LoginService and ProfileService are from your sub-projects, what you will need to do is add those libraries (presumably the target built from the sub-project) to "Link Binary With Libraries" in the Build Phases.

Additionally, you need to double check your Scheme for the main target you are building for and ensure that the targets for those sub-projects are being built (this would be in the Build stage shown on the left-side the Scheme dialog). If not, you will need to add them.

This is adding the library to the scheme. Note that if you have "Find Implicit Dependencies" checked, you should not have to do anything. I built a test case to double check (using Xcode 7.3.1)

[image]

Comment: HI Ben, thanks for trying to help out. This did not work, Adding subproject as dependency was required. -> https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: There are a few ways to solve for this. You can use target dependencies within the Build Phases provided you are using a sub project (which you are) as opposed to workspaces (which many people use instead of sub-projects). Additionally, if you have "Find Implicit Dependencies" (which should be the default) or add the target to the build in the scheme, it will also do the same. I've added a pic to show you what I mean. I prefer this method over target dependencies because more advanced projects use workspaces and target dependencies won't work.

Comment: Cool! and I am facing an issue that the images which are a part of sub-project are not appearing in main project. 
I get black screen when ViewControllers from sub-project are pushed on the main-project.

Comment: If you are using images within the sub-project for a static lib, those must be explicitly added as resources in the main project.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help. Cheers!